# Javascript - Multiple Arrays containing Variables

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and finding some difficulty in a task writing a program.

My task will be to write a program that will allow a user to enter their date of birth. The program then proceeds to give the corresponding Chinese Zodiac sign in an image and the number of days the user has been alive.

**What will be input?**

- The user's year of birth (assume a valid 4 digit year will be input)
- The user's month of birth (assume user will enter at least the first
  three letters of a month name, but this could be longer and could
  contain upper case characters, so it could be jan, Jan, january, or
  January, or other month names)
- The user's date (in the month) of birth (assume a valid date will be
  entered)

**Constants we will use**

Create and appropriately name constants to store the following values:

- A string containing month
  abbreviations    'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'
- The number of milliseconds in a day  1000*60*60*24
- The cycle of Chinese zodiac  12
- The year initialising Chinese Zodiac cycles  1924

**My code so far:**

```
var year = prompt('Enter year of birth as a 4 digit integer') // A prompt to enter the year of birth.
var month = prompt('Enter the name of the month of birth') // A prompt to enter the month of birth.
var date = prompt('Enter day of birth as an integer') // A prompt to enter the date of birth.
    var month = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"]
    var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    var month = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]
```

I'm having trouble with the input of the month of birth. I'm trying to write a code to assume user will enter at least the first three letters of a month name, but this could be longer and could contain upper case characters, so it could be jan, Jan, january, or January, or other month names.

Any help will be appreciated!

George

Comment: are you sure you need `month` variable defined 4 times?

Comment: PS: if you cannot do that yourself - it means you don't fit the position requirements, don't try to cheat your customer

Comment: It seems you have to learn some basics first. I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Just examine the first three letters of the month and disregard the rest of the string.

Comment: here's something to check out: http://www.javascriptsource.com/math-related/astrological-calculator.html

Comment: Hey Zerkms, I'm not sure if I need it defined 4 times, that's why I'm here to get help. As to me not fitting position requirements, I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not doing anything for anyone but myself.

Comment: Thanks Felix, cgatian and Mike S.

Comment: Yeah, as in I'm trying to learn by doing tasks online tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to shorten their input, and `.toLowerCase()` to convert it to lowercase.  Then match it to your array of months (the lowercase version).  Here's a bit to help you get started:

```
var month = prompt('Enter the name of the month of birth');
// Chop everything after the first 3 characters and make it lowercase
month = month.substr(0,3).toLowerCase();
// Store your array in months, differently named than the month input
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

// You can then use array.indexOf() to locate it in the array
// Not available in older browsers though
var pos = months.indexOf(month);
if (pos >= 0) {
   // valid month, number is pos
}
```

P.S. Don't forget the `;` at the end of each statement!

Comment: Thank you Michael, great help!

Answer (score 0):

Combine all of your possible month strings into one array:

```
var year = prompt('Enter year of birth as a 4 digit integer') // A prompt to enter the year of birth.
var month = prompt('Enter the name of the month of birth') // A prompt to enter the month of birth.
var date = prompt('Enter day of birth as an integer') // A prompt to enter the date of birth.
var possibleMonths = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec", 
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", 
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", 
    "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]
```

Then, iterate through that one array to check to see if your user entered one of those months:

```
var isValidMonth = false;

for (var i = 0; i < possibleMonths.length; i++){
    if (possibleMonths[i] === month){
        isValidMonth = true;
        break;
    }
}

alert(month + " is a valid month: " + isValidMonth);
```